# Testing hybrid apps on Amazon Device Farm

Tags: cordova, amazon-web-services

Is it possible testing hybrid mobile apps, made with Cordova, on Amazon Device Farm? In that case What should I upload appart from the apk file? As hybrid apps´tests are written in javascript I can´t upload the compliled test and the dependencies as if it were made with java.

Thanks.

Comment: Since you've also asked this question in [the AWS Device Farm forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=254174&tstart=0), the product team will respond in that thread.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon device farm does indeed test hybrid mobile apps.

All you will need is a .apk for Android or a .ipa for iOS.

> Make sure that your .ipa file is built for an iOS device and not for a simulator.

Then refer to Amazon's documention here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html#getting-started-create-run

See this statement taken from the Amazon documenation:

> Device Farm supports testing of native and hybrid Android, iOS, and Fire OS apps, including those created with PhoneGap, Titanium, Xamarin, Unity, and other frameworks. It supports remote access of Android apps for interactive testing.

Comment: But How should I upload the tests I want run. ADF ask for a compliled test with its dependencies that you buil with Maven in a zip file, but tests for a Cordova  app are made in javascript, so you neither compile them nor have dependencies to upload.

Answer (score 0):

Device Farm supports running tests using Appium Node